# div element to coldfusion variable

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have `<div id="test"></div>` displaying the value, which is great. However, if I view the source code of the html it still shows `<div id="test"></div>`. How can I convert `<div id="test"></div>` to the actual value/variable so I can use it in coldfusion for another query?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title></title> 
  <script> 
    function PassCatValue(element) { 
      var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text.toString(); 
    } 
  </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <Select id="box1" Name="colors" onChange="PassCatValue(this);"> 
    <OPTION value="0" Selected></OPTION> 
    <OPTION value="1">blue</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value="2">green</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value="3">red</OPTION> 
  </Select> 
  <br> 
  <div id="test"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason it's not displaying <div id="test"></div>. This is what I need to convert to a usable coldfusion variable.

Comment: You need to look up how SO does markdown

Comment: Why do you want to use an html string in a query? Are you talking about after the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment, but it is too long to put in the comment box.

In ColdFusion, if you want to display a variable, you do so with something like

```
<cfoutput>#text#</cfoutput>
```

As for Javascript, that is a completely different kind of question. Maybe you are looking to create a form and submitting that form, or using AJAX to process that form.

~~~~

Your question is probably going to get down voted because it is way to broad.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
<script>
function PassCatValue(element) {
    var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text.toString(); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<Select id="box1" Name="colors" onChange="PassCatValue(this);">
    <OPTION value="0" Selected></OPTION>
    <OPTION value="1">blue</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="2">green</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="3">red</OPTION>
</Select>
<br>
<div id="test"></div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: This is what you should consider doing. Take the content of this comment. Plus you original question and make a new question. Be sure to look up how markdown works. You can even look how I got the code to be formatted on your original question.